# How to make Castle Windsor TraceLoggerFactory output to Visual Studio output window?

Tags: castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

I'm building an application based on asp.net boilerplate, that uses castle Windsor logging facility.

I want to use the `TraceLoggerFactory` instead of the log4netFactory. (The latter works fine)

My goal is to output my logs to the output window in Visual Studio.

I switched out

```
f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
```

with

```
f => f.LogUsing<TraceLoggerFactory>().WithLevel(loggerLevel)
```

I expected this to output everything to the output window via the `defaulttracelistener`. But, while this code runs, it doesn't log anything.

If I look at the Logger object during debugging I see that all the logging levels are turned off, while the `loggerLevel` is set to Debug. So I assume that this is where the problem lies.

[image: Tracelogger Logger object]

If I use ConsoleFactory you get a Logger object with all log levels enabled

[image: Consolelogger Logger object]

But this isn't a console application, so I have no use for console logging.

How do I configure the `TraceLoggerFactory` properly, so that everything is directed to the output window?

Comment: check out @aaron's solution must solve your issue.

Comment: @gijswijs Did that work for you?

Comment: @aaron. Yes, it works smoothly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Castle's `TraceLoggerFactory` does not accept a `LoggerLevel` in its constructor.

You have to subclass it:

```cs
public class MyTraceLoggerFactory : TraceLoggerFactory
{
    private readonly LoggerLevel? level;

    public MyTraceLoggerFactory()
    {
    }

    public MyTraceLoggerFactory(LoggerLevel level)
    {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public override ILogger Create(string name)
    {
        if (level.HasValue)
        {
            return Create(name, level.Value);
        }
        return base.Create(name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
f => f.LogUsing<MyTraceLoggerFactory>().WithLevel(loggerLevel)
```